# Attribute error & CSRF token error with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send some data over a POST request and I get a "CSRF token is missing" error. I am trying to send the (anti) CSRF token using the `requests.post` headers like this:

```py
response = requests.post("my_url", data={"id_user": current_user_id.decode("utf-8")}, headers='Authorization: X-CSRF-TOKEN ' + session['csrf_token'])
```

However, on runtime, Python throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong, could someone help me assess why the error occurs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to write more detailed questions, so people can give more detailed responses. Make sure to include longer error messages (that include stacktraces and tracebacks), and show some code from the error location, so that users can help find out what went wrong. If someone writes an answer that helps or works for you, then click the little checkmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests` module takes the `headers` parameter as a Python dictionary. Instead of using a string like so:

```py
headers='Authorization: X-CSRF-TOKEN '+session['csrf_token']
```

You will need to use a dictionary like this:

```py
headers={'Authorization': 'X-CSRF-TOKEN ' + session['csrf_token']}
```

If you put the code all together, it looks like so:

```py
response = requests.post("my_url", data={"id_user": current_user_id.decode("utf-8")}, headers = {'Authorization': 'X-CSRF-TOKEN ' + session['csrf_token']})
```

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks for ur time!!

Comment: Click the checkmark next to my answer if the answer is valid. Have a good day!